# how to send F2 key to remote host using python

Tags: python, telnet

I have to send <kbd>F2</kbd> key to telnet host. How do I send it using python...using `getch()` I found that the character `<` used for the <kbd>F2</kbd> key but when sending `>`, its not working. I think there is a way to send special function keys but I am not able to find it. If somebody knows please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should start by posting the source code you have at the moment.

Comment: import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.open(HOST,PORT)

tn.write(idpass) #geting connected here

#now i just want send f2 key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extended keys (non-alphanumeric or symbol) are composed of a sequence of single characters, with the sequence depending on the terminal you have told the telnet server you are using. You will need to send all characters in the sequence in order to make it work. Here, using `od -c <<< '`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>`'` I was able to see a sequence of `\x1b0Q` with the `xterm` terminal.

Comment: thanks a lot lgnacio Vazquez-Abrams for ur quick reply i tried with sequence which u have given its still not working..for enter its working with esquape seq \r but i am still not geting it for f2

Comment: So then find out which terminal the remote side expects, and use *that* terminal's sequence.

Answer (score 3):

First, as [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035390/how-to-send-f2-key-to-remote-host-using-python/3035415#3035415) pointed out, you have to determine the exact sequence of characters sent by F2. On my machine, this happens to be `^[OQ`, where `^[` denotes an escape character with ASCII code 27. This is identical to what he got. You have to send the *exact* same byte sequence over telnet. Assuming that the correct sequence is the one I have shown above, it boils down to this:

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT)
tn.write(idpass)
tn.write("\x1b0Q")
tn.close()
```

In case you are wondering, `\x1b` stands for a character having ASCII code 27, since 27 in hexadecimal is `1b`.
This works on my machine (tested by a simple echo server on the receiving end), so if it does not work for you, it means that the remote end expects something else in place of an F2 keypress.

Comment: thanks for ur info Tamas
its worked at my end with key combination "\x1b2m"