# ASCII representation of Control-Backslash in python?

Tags: python, ascii

I need to send Ctrl-Backslash over an SSH connection, how would I get this into a string form?

Comment: You don't send keystrokes in the form of a string, but you can send them as keystrokes. This guide may help you, if you can replace `F2` with `Ctrl+Backslash`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035390/how-to-send-f2-key-to-remote-host-using-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, assuming that `fp` is the file-like object that you are writing to.

```
fp.write('\034')
```

Ps: I found this by typing `echo «CONTROL-V»«CONTROL-BACKSLASH» | od -c` in a Linux shell:

```
echo ^\ | od -c
0000000 034  \n
0000002
```

Comment: FWIW, I just tried this in Cygwin and got 

echo ^\ | od -c
0000000   ^      \n
0000003

Comment: I think you may have typed a literal caret character instead of a control-backslash there. ( Did you type SHIFT-6 or did you type CONTROL-\ ) ?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

I can't mark as solved for 5 minutes, but I'll do it soon! :)

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian - I've updated my answer. Hopefully that makes the process more clear.